# selenium - python - fetch the table row containing element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am fetching elements in the table:

```
<tbody id="actiontable-tbody">
<tr>
    <td class="letterbreak first">default</td>       <!-- first fetch this element -->
    <td class="letterbreak">Internal</td>
    <td class="action-btn-cell" id="id9c">
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="letterbreak first odd">opcua-module</td>
    <td class="letterbreak odd">Internal</td>
    <td class="action-btn-cell" id="id9d">
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I first fetch an element in one of the rows:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[text()='default']")
```

Now I want to fetch the row containing that element. I tried:

```
row = element.parent
```

But that is returning a `webDriver` object. How do I fetch the row with respect to the element in that row?

Edit: The ultimate goal is to then fetch the "action-btn-cell" element in that same row. So I was trying to go up a node and fetch the row node to then fetch the "action-btn-cell". Once I fetch the first element can I then fetch it's siblings? The fetch needs to be done starting with the first fetched element, either by going up to the row node or fetching the siblings, not by looping through all of the rows (it's a limitation by how the algorithm is implemented).

Comment: What are you exactly expecting by the term _...the row containing that element..._?

Comment: All of the elements within the same <tr>

Comment: @DebanjanB Or I should say the element containing those elements. Is a table row a fetch-able element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To identify the element `<td class="action-btn-cell" id="id9c">` use any of the follwoing **xpath**.

**option 1: use following-sibling**

```
//*[text()='default']/following-sibling::td[@class='action-btn-cell']
```

OR

```
//*[text()='default']/following-sibling::td[2]
```

**option 2: identify parent and then following child.**

```
//tr[.//*[text()='default']]/td[@class='action-btn-cell']
```

OR

```
//tr[.//*[text()='default']]/td[2]
```

---

**Example:**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[.//*[text()='default']]/td[@class='action-btn-cell']")
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract and print the texts belonging to the same `<tr>` that contains the text **default** using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[text()='default']/..")])
  ```
- Using *xpath*, *parent* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[text()='default']//parent::tr[1]")])
  ```
- Using *xpath*, *ancestor* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[text()='default']//ancestor::tr[1]")])
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//td[text()='default']//parent::tr[1]")))])
  ```
- Using *xpath*, *parent* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//td[text()='default']//parent::tr[1]")))])
  ```
- Using *xpath*, *ancestor* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//td[text()='default']//ancestor::tr[1]")))])
  ```